# Timestamp usage in rtp

Tags: ip, voip, rtp

I read RTP and I have one question.

Based on what I got, timestamp in rtp is for calculation of jitter and use it to de-jitter our packets. Basically I need it for TSoIP which I just need extract ASI from IP and pass to Modulator to process it.

I really appreciate if someone can help me to understand the usage of timestamp in receiver in order to receive ASi over IP. In other words: I didn`t find any good reference to help me to find what is timestamp and how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://toncar.cz/Tutorials/VoIP/VoIP_Basics_Jitter.html) you have a detailed discussion about the jitter and RTP.

The main aspect you are interested is the following:

> In the Real Time Protocol, jitter is measured in timestamp units. For example, if you transmit audio sampled at the usual 8000 Hertz, the unit is 1/8000 of a second.

In that page they also mention the relation between the timestamp and the receiver: The difference of relative transit times for the two packets is computed as:

```
D(i,j) = (Rj - Ri) - (Sj - Si) = (Rj - Sj) - (Ri - Si)
```

Si is the **timestamp** from the packet i and Ri is the **time of arrival** for packet i. You can also check to some examples [there](http://toncar.cz/Tutorials/VoIP/VoIP_Basics_Jitter.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question. How Does timestamp create? I mean for example what does this mean : timestamp : 776708079 the payload type is 33(decimal). How can we create the timestamp? is there any rules or.... Please help me to find it out. cheers

Comment: You can find it here: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/rtp/faq.html#timestamp-computed

Comment: Thanks. I read and again I confused with the sample from wireshark. 2dparityFEC-example.cap file the difference between each two frame is 79 and as we know the sampling base on rtp payload is 90KHz. How does this 79 comes from? I also have another example which the difference between two frame is 30 and sampling is 90KHz. I didn`t understand it. both of them are MPEG2-TS. Would you mind help me to understand these two number?